# 1-D, 2-D, 3-D: En-Dash , Em-dash, or hyphen

Tags: punctuation

I want to write the word as

> 1-dimension (1-D), 2-dimension (2-D)

Which is the correct punctuation mark?

Comment: This is off topic and should be on English.se

Comment: You can tell the difference? (sarcasm)  And in a lot of technical writing, no dash is used at all, e.g. 3D graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since *1-D* or *2-D* is an abbreviation of *one-dimensional* or *two-dimensional*, which are compound adjectives, you would use the hyphen.